# How to assign a value to a new column in a data frame based on a combination of multiple conditions on multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filtering, python-3.6

I have a data frame as below

```
data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
        'text1':['ab','cd','ef','gh','ij'],
        'text2':['ab','de','fh','hj','ij'],
        'text3':['xy','cd','mn','op','qr'],
        'flag1': ['y', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n'],
        'flag2': ['y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n'],
        'flag3': ['y', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'y']}

frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to add a new column - data['unique_text_count'] based on the following conditions:

1. if data['flag1'] == 'y' or data['flag2'] == 'y' or data['flag3'] == 'y' --> Any flag should be 'y'
2. Given one of the above conditions is True, if any row in the data frame has any of the flag values as 'y' then the corresponding values of data['text1'],data['text2'] & data['text3'] should be checked for unique values
3. Value of the new column - data['unique_text_count'] will be:

   0 - If all the flag values for that row are 'n'

   1 - If either of the flag values are 'y' and the count of unique values in the corresponding text columns where flag is 'y' is 1

   2 - If either of the flag values are 'y' and the count of unique values in the corresponding text columns where flag is 'y' is 2

   3 - If either of the flag values are 1 and the count of unique values in the corresponding text columns where flag is 'y' is 3

Final Result for the 5 rows will be:

data['unique_text_count'] = [2, 1, 3, 1, 1]

I have already tried to use iterrows() and iterate over each row and apply the conditions and calculate the count, but it is very time consuming. So, I am hoping for a better way to do it without having to iterate over each row individually

Comment: Please provide a simplified sample of what you want your DataFrame to look like. Also, you are wanting to do way too much in one go. Try to devise a solution for one step at a time, check to make sure one thing works, then go on to the next. You are giving us a whole list of stuff you want us to figure out for you. You are saying you;ve tried it, but you haven't posted up what you have tried and what were the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
frame['unique_text_count'] = (frame.filter(like='text')
                                   .where((frame.filter(like='flag') == 'y').to_numpy())
                                   .nunique(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   ID text1 text2 text3 flag1 flag2 flag3  unique_text_count
0   1    ab    ab    xy     y     y     y                  2
1   2    cd    de    cd     n     y     n                  1
2   3    ef    fh    mn     y     y     y                  3
3   4    gh    hj    op     y     n     n                  1
4   5    ij    ij    qr     n     n     y                  1
```

#### Details:

Use `filter` to select columns that match `like` parameter, then use `where` with a boolean matrix created from the == 'y' to return the text and nan for those with 'n'.  Lastly, use `nunique` with `axis=1` to count unique values on a row.

Comment: That is a slick answer.

Comment: @Ukrainian-serge Thanks.